# Spring STS learning for beginner

Tags: java, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

i am currently trying to learn how to use and code in STS but i have no clue where do i start on to get a good knowledge on how the coding is and how the flow goes.

I read some tutorial guides online but they are either hard to understand as there are many terms in them or hard to keep up with.

Some links that i have read
Links: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-beginner-tutorial-with-spring-tool-suite-ide

Is there any recommendation on anything that i can get this from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to take a look at:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mtI4vmsQ08

It is a Spring Tip video from Josh showing the Spring Tool Suite. It is a pretty good intro and should get you started.

After that, you can dive deeper with various other videos that are not very Spring Tool Suite specific, but introduce other concepts in Spring.

Comment: Thanks! it"s a great help!